# SQLite:Query for a specific time tracking scenario

Tags: database, sqlite, datetime, self-join

I have a specific scenario to track the in and out times for an inventory item.

I have a Inventory_track table of the following format

```
      Inv_id     in_time              out_time
1)   I_1111   2015-11-29 21:05:00.  2015-12-01 03:00:00
2)   I_1111  2015-12-01 05:00:00.  2015-12-01 09:00:00
3)   I_1111  2015-12-01 15:00:00.  2015-12-01 17:00:00
4)   I_1111  2015-12-01 21:00:00.  NULL
```

1. Anytime an inventory is placed into a Freezer, I insert a new record with an in_time
2. Anytime an inventory is taken out, I update the out_time ( not an insert, only an update)

At any given point, I want to find the **time that the inventory spent outside** the freeze location. Basically what I want to do is :

```
(record_2's in_time- record_1's out_time) + ( record_3's in_time- record_2's out_time)
```

and so on for a given inventory.
Can someone help me with a query in sqlite for this.  How do I go about using self joins for this scenario described above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a different approach. Find the difference between the biggest and the smallest in_time and subtract the sums of the intervals that the item stayed in the Freezer.

```
WITH inventory_time_in_freezer AS (
SELECT i1.inv_id, SUM(i1.out_time - i1.in_time) as time_in_freezer
FROM inventory_tack i1
WHERE out_time IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY i1.inv_id
)
SELECT i2.inv_id, MAX(i2.in_time) - MIN(i2.in_time) - iif.time_in_freezer
FROM inventory_tack i2
JOIN inventory_time_in_freezer iif ON iif.inv_id = i2.inv_id
GROUP BY i2.inv_id, iif.time_in_freezer
```

P.S. the query above is not tested and it's just to illustrate the idea.